# Составление регулярного выражения для 2 символов

Tags: javascript

У меня есть регулярное выражение: /\p/g, но оно не совсем так работает, как мне нужно. Оно должно считывать - "\p", а оно считывает только "p", мне нужно сделать регулярное выражение чтобы оно считывало только "\p"

Пример: \pИзи баг - из этого приложения должно "вырезаться" - "\p" - а не просто "p"
Надеюсь более понятно объяснил.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно спецсимвол экранировать, т.е. писать `\\p`

Comment: Не особо получилось, результат тот же самый.

Comment: Ну без кода тут что ещё можно сделать, только развести руками ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: test = div.replace(/\\p\\/g, '&emsp;&emsp;');

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: "Очень хорошее решение". Спасибо за потраченое время.

Comment: Странный человек. Хочет, чтобы ему помогли, но не хочет полностью воспроизводимую проблему предоставить, что поможет самому себе на 60%..... Ну ок. Удачи

Comment: Разве плохо описал проблему?

Comment: Или код не тот что нужно скинул? Та строка кода, что я вам скинул, это все, что  у меня есть. Я не знаю, что вы хотите от меня

Comment: Хорошо. Кто такой div? что в нём находится? судя по наименованию это html элемент и ты хочешь выпилить теги `p`.. А может и нет. Если да - то решение будет другое, если нет - то тоже может быть другое. Так что да, описание плохое.

Comment: Есть div блок, в нем находиться определенный текст, перед этим текстом ставлю "\p" и эта скажем так "команда" должна заменяться на что то другое(не важно на что), но как выше я описал проблему, у меня считывает только "P", а не "\p".

Comment: div блок !== строка. именно поэтому ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  ...почитай и запиши в вопрос полностью